# How to use a React component inside a Gatsby plugin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, gatsby

I have a Markdown plugin that fetches the markdown AST and replaces the `image` nodes by some HTML:

```js
module.exports = ({ markdownAST }) => {
  visit(markdownAST, 'image', node => {
      const html = `...`
      node.type = 'html'
      node.children = undefined
      node.value = html
  })

  return markdownAST
}
```

Now I don't want only to replace with HTML but I want to replace the `image`s with a full React component. This way, I can write some friendly Markdown like `![](image.png)` and it get replaced by a React component via this plugin. I don't want to type JSX inside Markdown, I want to keep the Markdown file as is.

How can I do this? I have a React component in a separate file waiting to be used.

If I used `gatsby-plugin-mdx`, I could add some React components in Markdown directly:

```
...
<Image />
...
```

But I want to keep the Markdown syntax and still use:

```
...
![](image.png)
...
```

But I want that behing the scene (in the transformer plugin I'm writing), the image gets converted to a React component and NOT ONLY into some custom HTML as shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gatsby does not provide functionality for storing React component instances in the GraphQL layer. This is critical because GraphQL query result data winds up being serialized as JSON (`page-data.json`) for each page/query.

You may be better off by simply using a good React-focused markdown renderer, like [markdown-to-jsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx), which would allow you to provide a React component or function to be used for any given HTML element:

```
import Markdown from "markdown-to-jsx"

export default ({ data }) => 
  <Markdown
    options={{
      overrides: {
        img: YourImageComponent,
        h1: ({ children, ...props }) => <h1 {...props}>Title: {children}</h1>,
      },
    }}
  >
    {data.page.markdownContent}
  </Markdown>
```